# how can i upload images and video to s3 in one single route using nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3, multer-s3

this is how i upload videos

```
router.post('/vid', upload.array('files', 5), async (req, res) => {
   try {
        const video = new Video();
        video.url = [];
        req.files.forEach((file) => {
          video.url.push(file.location);
        });
        const savedVideo = await video.save();
        res.json({
            message: 'Video uploaded successfully',
            video: savedVideo
        });
    } catch (error) {
       
    }
});
```

this how i upload pictures

```
router.post(`/products`, upload.array("photos", 10), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let product = new Product();
    product.photos.push(...req.files.map(({
      location
    }) => location));
    await product.save();
  } catch (error) {
   
  }
});
```

this is my middleware

```
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const multer = require("multer");
const multerS3 = require("multer-s3");

aws.config.update({
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWSSecretKey,
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWSAccessKeyId,
    region: 'eu-north-1', // Update the region to 'eu-north-1'
    correctClockSkew: true
  });

const s3 = new aws.S3();

const upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        bucket: 'ajibs',
        acl: 'public-read',
        metadata: (req, file, cb) => {
            cb(null, { fieldName: file.fieldname });
        },
        key: (req, file, cb) => {
            cb(null, Date.now().toString())
        }
    })
})

module.exports = upload;
```

both video and picture upload works fine if i use it in seperate route
please how can i upload both pictures and videos in one route

if i do this

```
upload.array(["photos","files"], 10)
```

i get this error

```
MulterError: Unexpected field
```

please how can i go about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this a working example ,what you'll need to do is change array to fields to get both photos and video, dont forget to add the photos name in your schema

```
router.post('/media', upload.fields([{ name: 'videos', maxCount: 5 }, { name: 'photos', maxCount: 10 }]), async (req, res) => {
   try {
        const video = new Video();
        video.title = req.body.title;
        video.url = [];
        video.photos = [];

        // Process uploaded videos
        if (req.files['videos']) {
            req.files['videos'].forEach((file) => {
                video.url.push(file.location);
            });
        }

        // Process uploaded photos
        if (req.files['photos']) {
            req.files['photos'].forEach((file) => {
                video.photos.push(file.location);
            });
        }

        console.log(video);

        // Save the video to the database
        const savedVideo = await video.save();

        res.json({
            message: 'Media uploaded successfully',
            video: savedVideo
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({
            error: 'An error occurred while uploading the media'
        });
    }
});
```